# Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, warnings

While installing a plugin I had the following error: *"The plugin does not have a valid header."*

But somehow, it worked. So after that, I created a page on which I added the short code suggested by the plugin help. When I clicked on update page, it returned the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/sites/j/jamworld876.net/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/templates/preset-display.php:1) in /var/sites/j/jamworld876.net/public_html/wp-admin/post.php on line 198

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/sites/j/jamworld876.net/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/templates/preset-display.php:1) in /var/sites/j/jamworld876.net/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216
```

The **preset-display.php** page that seems to be litigious contains:

```
<div class='wpcfs-search-preset wpcfs-search-preset-<?php echo $id?>'>
<?php
        WPCFSSearchForm::show_form($preset,"preset-$id");
?>
</div>
```

Except that, the plugin seemed to be working fine. I logged out. Everything was working fine on the front end. This is the page where I added the shortcode: **http://www.jamworld876.net/advanced-search**

But since I enabled this plugin, I'm unable to login. When I visit the login screen, the page is blank.

I suppose this php issue is the root of my problem. Though, I really need this plugin and I haven't found another one that does what I need but I cannot log in my backend no more.

Could someone help me fix this issue please? I really don't know ho to proceed to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says exactly what's going on.

You're outputting content, **before the data is finished being manipulated.** It's like you're trying to echo something but WordPress still has to do some stuff and it's telling you "No, no, let me do my thing first". **You're calling the echo too early.**

In short, you're 99% outputting before `wp_head`.

So, go to `header.php` and after the `body` div, put your

```
WPCFSSearchForm::show_form($preset,"preset-$id");
```

Or

```
require_once preset-display.php
```

Should work.

Thing is, this is really bad to do, so I suggest hooking `show_form` to an action and outputting it anywhere you want.

Comment: The issue is caused by the plugin Yoast SEO. If deactivated it, it works fine. So I'm trying to fix it without uninstalling Yoast SEO.